# How to support horizontal scaling for Corda Node?

Tags: blockchain, corda

We can achieve HA by using the Hot-Cold availability, where only one node is active at any given time.
Is it possible to have a Hot-Hot availability?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we support Hot-Cold functionality in Corda Enterprise, Hot-Hot is on the product road map.

Keep an eye on the releases/documentation for future releases.